# How do I call a function passing in a matrix in APL?

Tags: function, matrix, arguments, parameter-passing, apl

How do i call a function that i just wrote in APL, passing in a matrix? I have already tried many things but I can't seem to find the solution. I would greatly appreciate any help. 
I don't think this is a duplicate but please report if you find one :) 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe include some examples of things you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you declare otherwise, an APL function will accept any array as argument. For example, let's define a function which multiplies its argument by 2 and then adds 1:

```
      ∇ result←t2p1 argument
        result←1+2×argument
      ∇
```

Now we define a 3-by-4 matrix of some numbers, and ask for its value:

```
      matrix←3 4⍴3 1 4 1 5
      matrix
3 1 4 1
5 3 1 4
1 5 3 1
```

Finally, we apply the function to the matrix:

```
      t2p1 matrix
 7  3 9 3
11  7 3 9
 3 11 7 3
```